# error: stray '\240' in program

Tags: arduino, sensor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimad@s, debo realizar un programa de control termico sobre una pieza, es decir, mantener una pieza a cierta temperatura activando y desactivando un ventilador de 12v y un calefactor de 12v, todas estas temperatura seran captadas por un sensor dallas.

Este proceso consta de 4 partes, la pieza inicia con una tempeatura de 40°C ,la primera es donde se calienta la pieza a 50°C, luego debo mantenerla por 240 segundos, despues disminuir la temperatura de la pieza a 45° C y finalmente volver a mantenerla por otros 240 segundos, es por esto que he decidido utlizar la función millis () para poder controlar los tiempos en que funciona el codigo.

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

//se define el pin que vamos a usar con one wire
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensor (&oneWire);

int calefactor = 4;
int ventilador = 3;
float temperatura;
bool ventilador_activado = false;
bool calefactor_activado = false
float temp_max= 50;
float temp_min = 30;
float temp_inicial = 40;
float temp_final = 45;
int tiempo = millis()

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600)
  pinMode (ventilador,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (calefactor, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  sensor.requestTemperatures();
  temperatura = sensor.getTempCByIndex(0);

//Se inicia la parte de calentamiento de la pieza la cual demora 312,957 segundos en subir 10°C (40°C->50°)
//mientras la función millis nos entregue valores de tiempo entre 0 y 312957 (milisegundos) activará el calefactor y el ventilador estará desactivado
while (0 <tiempo < 312957){
  digitalWrite (calefactor, HIGH);
  calefactor_activado = true
  Serial.println ("Inicio del ciclo de Calentamiento -> " + String (temperatura));
  digitalWrite (ventilador, LOW)
  ventilador_activado = false
  delay(5000)
    Serial.println ("FIn del ciclo de Calentamiento -> " + String (temperatura));
}
//Se inicia el ciclo donde mantendremos la pieza a 50° por 240 segundos
//Esta parte solo se ejecutara cuando el tiempo del programa haya pasado el tiempo del calentamiento de la pieza mas el tiempo que se mantendre la pieza a 50°C (entre 49°C y 51°C)

  while (312957 <= tiempo < 552957){
  if (temperatura > (temp_max + 1)){
    digitalWrite(ventilador,HIGH);
    ventilador_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema De Refrigeración Activado -> " + String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite (calefactor,LOW);
    calefactor_activado = false;
  }
  if (temperatura < (temp_max - 1)){
    digitalWrite(calefactor,HIGH);
    calefactor_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite(ventilador, LOW);
    ventilador_activado = false;
  }
  }
  //Inicio del sistema de refrigeración de la pieza,esto demora 301,2 seg en disminuir a la temperatura final (50°C->45°C)
  while (552957 <= tiempo < 854157){ 
digitalWrite (calefactor, LOW);
  calefactor_activado = false;
  digitalWrite (ventilador, HIGH);
  ventilador_activado = true;
  Serial.println ("La pieza llego a la temperatura final -> " + String (temperatura));
  }
//Se inicia el segundo ciclo de estabilidad de la temperatura, en este caso la mantendremos entre 44°C y 46°C
//Utilizamos el mismo tiempo que en el ciclo 1 (240 segundos) por lo que este ciclo se ejecutara solo cuando haya pasado el tiempo de enfriamiento mas el tiempo acordado
  while (854157 <= tiempo < 1094157) {
    if (temperatura > (temp_final + 1)){
    digitalWrite(ventilador,HIGH);
    ventilador_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema De Refrigeración Activado -> " + String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite (calefactor,LOW);
    calefactor_activado = false;
  }
  if (temperatura < temp_final - 1){
    digitalWrite(calefactor,HIGH);
    calefactor_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite(ventilador, LOW);
    ventilador_activado = false;
  }
  }
}
```

Los errores que aparecen mayoritariamente son;

```
controltermicofinal:85:2: error: stray '\240' in program
     calefactor_activado = true;
  ^
controltermicofinal:85:4: error: stray '\302' in program
     calefactor_activado = true;
    ^
controltermicofinal:85:5: error: stray '\240' in program
     calefactor_activado = true;
     ^
controltermicofinal:86:1: error: stray '\302' in program
     Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
 ^
controltermicofinal:86:2: error: stray '\240' in program
     Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
  ^
controltermicofinal:86:4: error: stray '\302' in program
     Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
    ^
controltermicofinal:86:5: error: stray '\240' in program
     Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
     ^
controltermicofinal:86:63: error: stray '\302' in program
     Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
                                                               ^
controltermicofinal:86:64: error: stray '\240' in program
     Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
                                                                ^
controltermicofinal:89:1: error: stray '\302' in program
   }
 ^
controltermicofinal:89:2: error: stray '\240' in program
   }
  ^
C:\Users\guill\Desktop\controltermicofinal\controltermicofinal.ino: In function 'void setup()':
controltermicofinal:25:4: error: expected ';' before 'pinMode'
   pinMode (ventilador,OUTPUT);
    ^~~~~~~
exit status 1
stray '\302' in program
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Entonces el problema concreto cual es? no calienta? no enfria? no hace nada?

Comment: Tiene pinta de que no compila

Comment: Para tu proyecto te conviene usar PID (Proporcional, Integrador, Derivativo), que es un método de control estándar de la industria para estas aplicaciones. Busca "Control PID" en YT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas que el código compile, aquí lo tienes:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

//se define el pin que vamos a usar con one wire
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensor (&oneWire);

int calefactor = 4;
int ventilador = 3;
float temperatura;
bool ventilador_activado = false;
bool calefactor_activado = false;
float temp_max= 50;
float temp_min = 30;
float temp_inicial = 40;
float temp_final = 45;
int tiempo = millis();

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode (ventilador,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (calefactor, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  sensor.requestTemperatures();
  temperatura = sensor.getTempCByIndex(0);

//Se inicia la parte de calentamiento de la pieza la cual demora 312,957 segundos en subir 10°C (40°C->50°)
//mientras la función millis nos entregue valores de tiempo entre 0 y 312957 (milisegundos) activará el calefactor y el ventilador estará desactivado
if (0 < tiempo && tiempo < 312957){
  digitalWrite (calefactor, HIGH);
  calefactor_activado = true;
  Serial.println ("Inicio del ciclo de Calentamiento -> " + String (temperatura));
  digitalWrite (ventilador, LOW);
  ventilador_activado = false;
  delay(5000);
    Serial.println ("FIn del ciclo de Calentamiento -> " + String (temperatura));
}
//Se inicia el ciclo donde mantendremos la pieza a 50° por 240 segundos
//Esta parte solo se ejecutara cuando el tiempo del programa haya pasado el tiempo del calentamiento de la pieza mas el tiempo que se mantendre la pieza a 50°C (entre 49°C y 51°C)

  if (312957 <= tiempo && tiempo < 552957){
  if (temperatura > (temp_max + 1)){
    digitalWrite(ventilador,HIGH);
    ventilador_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema De Refrigeración Activado -> " + String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite (calefactor,LOW);
    calefactor_activado = false;
  }
  if (temperatura < (temp_max - 1)){
    digitalWrite(calefactor,HIGH);
    calefactor_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite(ventilador, LOW);
    ventilador_activado = false;
  }
  }
  //Inicio del sistema de refrigeración de la pieza,esto demora 301,2 seg en disminuir a la temperatura final (50°C->45°C)
  while (552957 <= tiempo && tiempo < 854157){ 
digitalWrite (calefactor, LOW);
  calefactor_activado = false;
  digitalWrite (ventilador, HIGH);
  ventilador_activado = true;
  Serial.println ("La pieza llego a la temperatura final -> " + String (temperatura));
  }
//Se inicia el segundo ciclo de estabilidad de la temperatura, en este caso la mantendremos entre 44°C y 46°C
//Utilizamos el mismo tiempo que en el ciclo 1 (240 segundos) por lo que este ciclo se ejecutara solo cuando haya pasado el tiempo de enfriamiento mas el tiempo acordado
  if (854157 <= tiempo && tiempo < 1094157) {
    if (temperatura > (temp_final + 1)){
    digitalWrite(ventilador,HIGH);
    ventilador_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema De Refrigeración Activado -> " + String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite (calefactor,LOW);
    calefactor_activado = false;
  }
  if (temperatura < temp_final - 1){
    digitalWrite(calefactor,HIGH);
    calefactor_activado = true;
    Serial.println("Sistema de Calentamiento Activado -> " +  String (temperatura));
    digitalWrite(ventilador, LOW);
    ventilador_activado = false;
  }
  }
  tiempo = millis();
}
```

Aunque todavía tendrás que trabajar en los bucles y las actualizaciones del tiempo. Los errores que te daba de stray\302 y stray\240 eran debidos a la falta de ; en el final de muchas de las líneas

EDIT: He sustituido los while por if y arreglado las condiciones para que sea funcional
[image: Prueba de compilación]

Comment: @GuillermoTobar te pase los links para que sepas como funiona el sitio... vota las respuestas que te sirviron y acepta aquella que te sirvio mas.. mira el [tour] que te explica todo

Comment: @GuillermoTobar No soy ningún genio, pero gracias. Mira los cambios que he añadido al código, sustituyendo los while() por if(). Es como se suelen hacer las cosas en arduino. Además he añadido al final un tiempo= milis() para que se mantenga siempre actualizado. Un saludo y suerte con la carrera

Comment: me aparece un error en el tiempo= millis() ('milis' was not declared in this scope
) que agregaste al final del codigo para mantenerlo actualizado

Comment: @GuillermoTobar que corrija el codigo en la respuesta. este es un sitio colaborativo y la info esta aca... tambien podes corregirlo vos y editar la respuesta!!!!

Comment: Puse una sola L en milis, se escribe con dos LL, millis(). De todas maneras está corregido hace rato, copiaste justo antes de corregirlo, @GuillermoTobar

Answer (score 0):

Podría sugerirte esta lógica usando funciones a grandes rasgos.

Aplícala con todos los detalles particulares de tu proyecto.

```
int leertemperatura()
{
   //logica para leer temperatura
}

void encenderCalentador()
{
  //Lógica para encender el calentador y apagar el enfriador
}

void encenderCalentador()
{
  //Lógica para encender el enfriador y apagar el calentador
}


void etapa1(){
  unsigned long milisiniciales; 
  unsigned long milisactuales;
  const unsigned long tiempomaximo = 240000; 
  const int temp_max = 50;
  boolean calentado = false;
  boolean cicloiniciado = false;
 
  temperatura = leertemperatura();
  

  while(!calentado)
  {
    if(temperatura < temp_max )
      encenderCalentador();

    if(temperatura > temp_max )
      encenderEnfriador();

    if(temperatura >= temp_max && !calentado)
    {
      calentado = true;
      cicloiniciado = true;
      milisiniciales = millis();
    }

   delay(500);
  }

  while(cicloiniciado)
  {
    if(temperatura < temp_max )
      encenderCalentador();

    if(temperatura > temp_max )
      encenderEnfriador();

    milisactuales = millis();

    if((milisactuales - millisiniciales) >= tiempomaximo))
       cicloiniciado = false;

   delay(500);
  }
}

void etapa2()
{
   //Algo similar que etapa uno

}


void loop{
  etapa1();
  etapa2();
}
```